# load javascript after the html has rendered

Tags: javascript

The below script works perfectly fine if the p tag is placed above and script placed below

```
<p id="dom_intro">Hello</p> 

<script>
x=document.getElementById("dom_intro");
document.write("<p>This is the text of dom intro" + x.innerHTML + "Howzzat </p>");
</script>
```

If the same code where the script is placed first and html p tag is placed below the script it does not work, I am getting error x is null or undefined

```
<script>
x=document.getElementById("dom_intro");
document.write("<p>This is the text of dom intro" + x.innerHTML + "Howzzat </p>");
</script>

<p id="dom_intro">Hello</p>
```

I tried pasting the script in external javascript file and placed at the head section
I am getting the same error. Is there any javascript or jquery script to load the javascript file after the html has rendred

Answer (score 1):

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(){function(){
//yourcode

});
```

And Javascript

```
window.onload=function(){
//your code

}
```

The document ready in jquery executes the function when the DOM is ready, that means before some images are downloaded.

Window.onload is fired when page is completely ready, that is when all images are finished loading.

Comment: As said I used window.onload but document.write within the script overwrites the entire html page. Should I use window.onload for all the functions I delcare in my javascript file

Comment: u cant use document.write!!!! you shouldnt..read some books on javascript..some more if u already started..use document.getElementById and innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

you need to access the element once the dom is ready. you are getting this error because your trying to access the p tag before the dom getting loaded.

this may fix your problem

```
window.onload = function(){ 
  // your javascript here
   x=document.getElementById("dom_intro");
   document.write("<p>This is the text of dom intro" + x.innerHTML + "Howzzat </p>");

}
```

Comment: Thanks.
As said I used window.onload but document.write within the script overwrites the entire html page. Should I use window.onload for all the functions I delcare in my javascript file

Comment: well its document.write..u cant do that..the entire page will be re written!!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are rendering your code as they see it (lineary). The here problem is that your script tries to access something that doesn't exists yet so it's common practice to wait until all DOM elements are ready and then execute script.

Please look here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Which is equivalent to calling:

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The <script> content is executed where you place it, so in the second case, you are trying to use "dom_intro" before it is declared. But you're trying to load the javascript AFTER the html has rendered, so you don't want to write the script BEFORE the html content, right?

The usual way to load JS files are just before the </body> close tag. That way you'll be sure that any html won't be downloaded before all your HTML is loaded.

And if you want to wait for the HTML to finish loading before executing any JS, you must do something like this:

Plain javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // do_whatever_you_want
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do_whatever_you_want
}
```